Unexpected dart sdk version on android studio/flutter on linux
I am trying to get flutter/android studios to work on linux, and unable to
flutter run
due to an Unexpected kernel SDK version error.
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Unhandled exception:
Unexpected Kernel SDK Version 415669e260 (expected 138695ec00).
#0      BinaryBuilder._readAndVerifySdkHash (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:657)
#1      BinaryBuilder._verifyComponentInitialBytes (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:874)
#2      BinaryBuilder.readComponent.<anonymous closure> (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:697)
#3      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:173)
#4      BinaryBuilder.readComponent (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:695)
#5      _InitializationFromSdkSummary._prepareSummary (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:2529)
#6      _InitializationFromUri.initialize (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:2603)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      IncrementalCompiler._ensurePlatformAndInitialize (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:1402)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:272)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CompilerContext.clear (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:130)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:77)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:636)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1384)
<asynchronous suspension>
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             185ms
Failed to compile application.


I guess It's caused by unmatching dart version, but have no idea what dart version 138695ec00 is
Did flutter run on android studio
Linux version : Arch Linux 6.8.2-arch2-1(64-bit)
Current Dart version : 3.5.0-128.0.dev
No problem in flutter doctor
